# Extract bit from two dimensional bit-array

Tags: c#, arrays, artificial-intelligence, bitwise-operators, bit

For an Minimax-Algorithm I code I want to experiment with bitwise operations to speed things up. Each gamestate is saved as an UInt128 and describes a 4x4 tile-based board. Each tile can have a value from 0 to 32 (exclusive) so 5 bits per tile.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0-4   | 5-9   | 10-14 | 15-19 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 20-24 | 25-29 | 30-34 | 35-39 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 40-44 | 45-49 | 50-54 | 55-59 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 60-64 | 65-69 | 70-74 | 75-79 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

For actually performing operations on the board I need to extract a 3x3 block out of the 4x4 based on the center of the 3x3. How would I go about to to that? I have no problem doing it manually by simple acessing every cell via bitshifting, but I wonder if there is a faster way.

Thanks in Advance!

(Language is C# in case that matters)

Answer (score 2):

Bit ops are pretty fast. Since you already have no problem doing it manually using bit shifting, make a copy of the 4x4 and reduce it to 3x3, then perform your operations on that, and see if there are performance issues.

If performing your 'operations' means read only, depending on the cost of directly accessing bits in the 4x4 versus copying, shifting and still need to access to the 3x3, then the extra copy may prove more expensive.

On a side note, since you are using a 128 bit type, it would be possible to use a byte[16] (or byte[9] for the 3x3 operations). This would make it faster to access individual cells.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. Wouldn't the byte-array become quite expensive when copying it around? (using them inside structs)

Comment: That was just something I suggested to look at. My point was more that extracting one 128 bit array to another, is going to have a cost and so will reading/writing bit masks (computing positions, etc.). You could also create a couple of structs (presumably what the UInt128 is?), one with 16 byte variables Cell1-16 (much like the System.Numerics.Matrix4x4) and another with Cell1-9. Since these are now ValueType's (as opposed to the byte array which is a reference type) it will be copied like the UInt128.